# Move the tilemap in a camera

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a camera that renders a TiledMap.

I would like to simulate vertical scrolling, moving down the tiledmap inside the camera (the camera remains firm).

how can I achieve this?

**EDIT**
In the create method

```
map=new TmxMapLoader().load("Map.tmx");
this.renderer=new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
this.camera=new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
this.camera.translate(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
this.camera.update();
```

In the render method

```
this.renderer.setView(camera);
this.renderer.render();
camera.update();
```

Comment: no one knows how to get to this?

Comment: could you provide some code? It is unclear what are you asking.

Comment: Ok yes sorry.I explain better: I have a camera that renders a TiledMap and I want to implement vertical scroll but I do not want to move the y coordinate of the camera, but I want to move the location of tiledmap. Now insert the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a second camera, render your tiles with it, and move only this camera:

create method:

```
this.scrollingCamera =new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
this.scrollingCamera.translate(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
this.scrollingCamera.update();
```

and then, during rendering:

```
this.renderer.setView(scrollingCamera);
this.renderer.render(); // Render tiles
this.scrollingCamera.translate(SCROLLING_SPEED.X, SCROLLING_SPEED.Y);
this.scrollingCamera.update();

this.renderer.setView(camera);
// Render other stuff
camera.update();
```